# Mulitply entire array with entries from another array independently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have an array with a size of 2x1 and another array with the same size. I want to multiply each element from the second array separately with the first array to get an array with a size of 4x1. Lets assume that I have the following array:

```
my_array_1 = array([[1.],
                    [1.]])
```

and

```
my_array_2 = array([[5.],
                    [1.]])
```

the result thus should be as follows:

```
result_array = array([[5.],
                     [5.],
                     [1.],
                     [1.]])
```

I am aware of iterating over indices the obtain the resulting array with a for-loop, but is there a more effiecent way e.g. a NumPy function call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`numpy.kron`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html):

```
In [35]: np.kron(my_array_2, my_array_1)                                        
Out[35]: 
array([[5.],
       [5.],
       [1.],
       [1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most straightforward for me:

```
>>> a1 = array([[5],[1]])
>>> a2 = array([1,2])
>>> (a1*a2).flatten()
array([ 5, 10,  1,  2])
```

but if you want exactly what you're asking for, you should go with [Warren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611581/mulitply-entire-array-with-entries-from-another-array-independentely#62611642).

Comment: Ravel is better than flatten since the result doesn't need to be copied.